# cannot load underlying module bmspush

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am following the instruction for Swift on https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/c_ios_enable.html

When trying to import BMSPush, I get the following error: "cannot load underlying module bmspush". 
Importing BMSCore hasn't been a problem.
Install pod windows said:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (2.0.2)
Using BMSAnalyticsAPI (1.0.1)
Using BMSCore (1.0.2)
Using BMSPush (1.0.3)
Using MBProgressHUD (0.9.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile and 5 total
pods installed.
```

I have seen the answer from here but it didn't help: [No such module 'BMSPush' after SDK installation with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448766/no-such-module-bmspush-after-sdk-installation-with-cocoapods/36451406#36451406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions and too got "cannot load underlying module BMSPush." However, when I clicked build, the application built fine and the red error went away.